# Bash | port killing loop fails

Tags: linux, bash, kill, for

I am trying to create a bash function which should kill all processes using some ports specified in `port_array`. The `kill-port` function works if I call it myself with a port e.g. with `kill-port "80";`. But if I call it inside the for loop I get some strange error from `kill`:

```
Usage:
kill [options] <pid> [...]

Options:
<pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
-<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
                    specify the <signal> to be sent
-l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
-L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table

-h, --help     display this help and exit
-V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see kill(1).
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

port_array=( 5057 5061 5056 );
function kill-ports () {
    ports=( "$@" )
    for i in "${ports[@]}"; 
    do
        kill-port $i;
    done
};

function kill-port () {
   lsof -i tcp:"$1" | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill;
}


kill-ports "${port_array[@]}";
```

I am probably overseeing my mistake, but I would be thankful if someone could tell me what the problem here is.

Regards,

Silas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution, thanks to @StéphaneChazelas comment:

"Just do:

`lsof -ti "tcp:$1" | xargs -r kill`,

that's what `-t` is for (and `-r` tells **xargs** not to run the command if there's no argument. That's for **GNU** xargs. Some other implementations like **FreeBSD** do that automatically)"

In the end it looks like this and **also** works (Some cleanup by me too):

```
#!/bin/bash

port_array=( 5057 5061 5056 );
kill-ports() {
   for port in "$@"; 
   do
       kill-port "$port";
   done
};

kill-port () {
   lsof -ti "tcp:$1" | xargs -r kill;
}

kill-ports ${port_array[@]};
```

**EDIT:**

@PSkocik's solution was posted after @StéphaneChazelas comment, but works fine too:

```
#!/bin/bash

port_array=( 5057 5061 5056 );

kill-ports() {
   for port in "$@"; do fuser -n tcp "$port" -k -TERM; done
}

kill-ports ${port_array[@]};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
kill-ports() {
   for port in "$@"; do fuser -n tcp "$port" -k -TERM; done
}
```

(You absolutely do not need the quotes in this case, but it's always good to use them, or else you'll get complains/edits from people.)

Answer (score -3):

Try appending -9 to kill

```
lsof -i tcp:"$1" | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill -9;
```

Comment: That won't make any difference, it will just kill those programs it finds in a less elegant way. The issue here is that there are sometimes no programs listening on the port in question.

Comment: [Not a good suggestion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...)

Comment: Error checking is author's resposibility - He needs to take care of those.

Comment: This doesn't work, same error. But Stéphane Chazelas solution works, I am just waiting for his answer on whether he or me should post the solution

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23953/discussion-on-answer-by-alpa-bash-kill-ports-loop-fails).